# What is the proper MIME type for .el files?

Tags: elisp

I'm uploading a .el file to my server, and I'd like to set my `.htaccess` so that the file gets downloaded rather than displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper type for Emacs Lisp files is `text/elisp`.

This can be added to your `.htaccess` with this line:

```
AddType text/elisp el
```

Firefox, for example, now recognizes it as "Emacs Lisp source code", and offers to download it.

Comment: I don't see it listed on <https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml>, and Emacs doesn't seem to know about it, either.  Are you sure that's really a proper content-type for it?

Comment: @SamB Setting that MIME type [works for me](http://zck.me/tictactoe/tictactoe.el).